# Why use cross validation?

Tags: machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, cross-validation, kaggle

I am entering several Kaggle Machine Learning competitions at the moment and I just have a quick question. Why do we use cross validation to assess our algorithms effectiveness in these competitions?

Surely in these competitions your score in the public leaderboard, where your algorithm is tested against actual live data would give you a more accurate representation of your algorithms efficacy?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs on http://stats.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cross-validation is a necessary step in model construction. If cross-validation gives you poor results, there is no sense in even trying it on live data. Your set on which you are training and validating is also live data, isn't it? So, the results should be similar. Without validating your model you don't have any insight into its performance whatsoever. Models which give 100% accuracy on training set could give random results on validation set.

Let me re-iterate, cross-validation is not a replacement for live data test, it is a part of model construction process.

Comment: Thanks for this response. So my general plan of action should be to do an initial CV test on my model. If this performs promisingly, then I should plug it into the live test. If it performs very well in CV and poorly for the live test, then I am likely overfitting. Both metrics are needed to give me a good idea of how the model is performing. Have I understood correctly?

Comment: @SimonKiely This is kind of a rough idea, but there is quite a bit more to it (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-validation_(statistics)). Some tips are here http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/19048/what-is-the-difference-between-test-set-and-validation-set I also recommend you to browse through some literature because it is not as easy as it seems at first...

Comment: @SimonKiely If you perform very well on the training set, then you have successfully found features that separate your training set well. We perform cross validation to 'validate' that our training examples are *representative* of the real-world dataset. That's the key--if we can build a model on our training set, and use that model to successfully predict an independent set (the test set), we can say with good confidence that this model will generalize to the real-world set of data.